# The most general real functions $f(x,y,z)$

Tags: real-analysis

What is the most general real functions $f(x,y,z)$ that satisfying
$$ f(x,y,z)=f(y,z,x)? $$

Of course, it includes all symmetric functions of 3 variables and of the form $ g(x,y)g(y,z)g(z,x) $ or $ g(x,y)+g(y,z)+g(z,x)$ for any function $g(x,y).$ Is there any other kinds of functions that satisfy the condition mentioned above ?

Answer (score 1):

such a condition implies $f(x,y,z) = f(y,z,x) = f(z,x,y)$ for all $x,y,z$. This splits $\mathbb R^3$ into different equivalence classes, most of them having exactly $3$ elements but some having exactly one element ( the ones with a tuple of the form $(x,x,x)$ ).

All of the functions are obtained by simply assigning a real value to each equivalence class.